# Cannot use command "maas-region" on ubuntu 20.04. ; getting "distribution" not found error when trying workaround

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I have installed maas following the [Ubuntu Openstack Cluster Installation Site](https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#cluster-deployment), but when I get to

```
sudo maas-region apikey --username=admin
```

I get error

```
sudo: maas-region: command not found
```

Realizing that there is no binary in /snap/bin for maas-region, but in /snap/maas/current/bin, I tried

```
sudo /snap/maas/current/bin/maas-region apikey --username=admin
```

but that gave me error

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'maas==2.7.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Has anyone else encountered this error and, if so, found a workaround to share ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo maas apikey --username admin` instead.